# I have an R dataframe which contains a list of other dataframes. How do I only retain specific dataframes based on rows or columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, multiple-columns

Code to obtain box_scores_2016

```
urls <- c("https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201610250CLE.html", 
          "https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201610250POR.html",
          "https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201610250GSW.html")
          
urls_df <- data.frame(urls)

df_htmls <- urls_df %>%
  mutate_at("urls", str_replace, "https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/", "")

order_htmls <- df_htmls$urls

paths <- here(order_htmls)

a <- c(1:3)
a <- paste0("a0", a)
numbers <- as.data.frame(a)

numbers$a <- paste0(numbers$a, ".html")
numbers_htmls <- numbers$a

for (i in 1:3) {
  download_html(urls[i])
}

for (i in 1:3) {
  file.rename(paths[i], numbers_htmls[i])
}

html_list <- list.files("...", pattern = ".html")

urltxt <- lapply(html_list, function(x) try(readLines(x)))

urltxt <- gsub("-->", "", gsub("<!--", "", urltxt))

doc_2016 <- htmlParse(urltxt)

tables_2016 <- xpathApply(doc_2016, "//table")

box_scores_2016 <- lapply(tables_2016[c(1:63)], function(i) readHTMLTable(i))

for (i in 1:3) {
  unlink(html_list)
}
```

[data frame list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1r5zq.png)

Please see attached picture. I would like to create a new df with just dataframes of 21 columns. I have tried a few different things.

Such as:

```
box_score_variables <- c("Starters", "MP", "FG", "FGA", "FG%", "3P", "3PA", 
                         "3P%", "FT", "FTA", "FT%", "ORB", "DRB", "TRB", "AST", 
                         "STL", "BLK", "TOV", "PF", "PTS", "+/-")

box_score_variables  <- lapply(box_scores_2016, function(x) x[(names(x) %in% box_score_variables)])

box_score_variables <- rbindlist(box_score_variables)
```

However, some of the dataframes with less than 21 columns also have Starters and MP columns. Thus, this solution doesn't work.

I have also tried the other way around (i.e., removing the irrelevant variables). However, some columns are named in this format: "True Shooting PercentageA measure of shooting efficiency that takes into account 2-point field goals, 3-point field goals, and free throws." data-over-header="Advanced Box Score Stats" >TS%"
and I have no idea how to rename columns with such a name.

Please advice.

I would be very greatfull!

Comment: Could you write up a subset of your dataframe list so we can see the structure? I'm finding it a bit hard to know what you mean without this.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Will write it now.

Comment: Added code to abtain a subset of my dataframe list.